# Lookup field value from VF page not been assigned to Visual Flow variable

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I have created an VF page and embedded a visual workflow in it. VF page has an lookup field, but I am having problem in assigning value to the flow variable through this.I have to click on save button and pass the arguments through url to same page then assign the values in constructor.
Can this be done without clicking on save button?
For lookup I have tried using Dynamic choice element but the problem is that it displays the result on next screen once you enter the String to be searched
The visual force fields and flow fields appear separately.Is there any way I can Display it in Same page?
    Here is the sample code-

[image]

```
<apex:page controller="AmendmentCreationWizardController" title="New Contract Amendment">

<apex:sectionHeader title="New Contract Amendment"/>
   <div style ="margin-top:50px;">
    <apex:form >
        <div style="margin-left:80px;">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Contract Emailed To" style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!Contact.ReportsToId}"  />
          <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!getContactDetails}"/>
      </div>
      </apex:form>
  <flow:interview name="Contract_Amendment_Creation_Wizard" interview="{!myFlow}" buttonLocation="bottom" finishLocation="{!newPage}">
        <apex:param name="ContactId" value="{!selectedContactId}"/>
        <apex:param name="contract_Id" value="{!selectedContractId}"/>
    </flow:interview>
    </div>
</apex:page>

-----Controller----
public with sharing class AmendmentCreationWizardController{

    public PageReference getNewPage() {
    if(myFlow!=null){
        if(myFlow.AmendmentType =='Booth Change Amendment'){
           return new PageReference('/apex/BoothChangeAmendmentWizard?id='+myFlow.contract_Id+'&AmdId='+myFlow.amendment_Id);
         system.debug('ContractId->>'+myFlow.contract_Id);
         system.debug('ContractId->>'+myFlow.AmendmentType);
         system.debug('ContractId->>'+myFlow.amendment_Id);
        // return new PageReference('/apex/BoothChangeAmendmentWizard');

        }else{
        if(myFlow.AmendmentType =='Cancellation'){
            return new PageReference('/apex/OpportunityCancelWizard?conAmdId='+myFlow.amendment_Id+'&id='+myFlow.contract_Id);
        }else{
            return new PageReference('/'+myFlow.amendment_Id);
        }
        }
    }
        return new PageReference('null');
    }


  public String selectedContactId{get;set;}
  public String selectedContractId{get;set;}
  public Contact contact {get;set;}
  Public string Conract;
  public Flow.Interview.Contract_Amendment_Creation_Wizard myFlow{get;set;}

  //public flow.interview.Contract_Amendment_Creation_Wizard dflow{get;set;}

  public AmendmentCreationWizardController() {
      selectedContactId = 'test';  
      selectedContactId  = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ContactId');
      //selectedContactId = '003n0000008T4WL';
      selectedContractId =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ContractId');
      contact = new Contact();
  }

  public PageReference getContactDetails() {
        selectedContactId = Contact.ReportsToId;
        PageReference congratsPage = Page.ContractAmendmentCreationWizard;
        congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
        congratsPage.getParameters().put('ContactId',selectedContactId);
        congratsPage.getParameters().put('ContractId',selectedContractId);
        return congratsPage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following its working,
The problem here is that it is refreshing the page.
Can I do this without refreshing the page?

```
<apex:page Controller="AmendmentCreationWizardController" title="New Contract Amendment">

<apex:sectionHeader title="New Contract Amendment"/>
<div style ="margin-top:50px;">
    <apex:form >
        <div style="margin-left:80px;">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Contract Emailed To" style="font-weight:bold;" rendered="{!selectedContactId == NULL}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!Contact.ReportsToId}" rendered="{!selectedContactId == NULL}" onChange="test1()"/>

          <apex:actionFunction name="test1" action="{!getContactDetails}" rerender="Test_2"/>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="Test_2">  
    <flow:interview name="Contract_Amendment_Creation_Wizard" interview="{!myFlow}"  id="Flow_1"  buttonLocation="bottom"  finishLocation="{!newPage}">
        <apex:param name="ContactId" value="{!selectedContactId}"/>
        <apex:param name="contract_Id" value="{!selectedContractId}"/>
  </flow:interview>
  </apex:outputPanel>

</div>
</apex:page>
```